# Не корректное отображение иконок

Tags: android, ui

Иконки, что я импотрировал после билда на телефон отображаются некорректно на некоторых устройствах, хотя, в android studio все иконки вырисованы правильно.

Как решить данную проблему?

[image: Корявые иконки]

пример кода xml щита(последняя иконка):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="60dp"
android:height="60dp"
android:viewportWidth="60"
android:viewportHeight="60">

<path
    android:fillColor="#5b5b5b"
    android:pathData="M44.39,14.86,31.53,11.21a5.59,5.59,0,0,0-3.05,0L15.61,14.86A2.19,2.19,0,0,0,14,16.93V27.18a22.63,22.63,0,0,0,4.24,13.2,24.14,24.14,0,0,0,10.91,8.46,2.33,2.33,0,0,0,1.7,0,24.13,24.13,0,0,0,10.91-8.46A22.63,22.63,0,0,0,46,27.18V16.93A2.19,2.19,0,0,0,44.39,14.86ZM44.2,27.18A21,21,0,0,1,40.27,39.4a22.35,22.35,0,0,1-10.1,7.84 0.47 0.47,0,0,1-0.34,0,22.35,22.35,0,0,1-10.1-7.84A21,21,0,0,1,15.8,27.18V16.93a0.44 0.44 ,0,0,1,0.32-0.41L29,12.87a3.73,3.73,0,0,1,2,0l12.86,3.65a0.44 0.44 ,0,0,1,0.32 0.41 Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#cd642b"
    android:pathData="M40,18.69,30.38,16a1.4,1.4,0,0,0-0.76,0L20,18.69a1.31,1.31,0,0,0-1,1.24v7.25A17.9,17.9,0,0,0,22.55,37.8a19.15,19.15,0,0,0,6.83,5.78,1.39,1.39,0,0,0,1.25,0,19.15,19.15,0,0,0,6.83-5.78,17.9,17.9,0,0,0,3.48-10.62V19.93A1.31,1.31,0,0,0,40,18.69Zm-0.83,8.49A16.23,16.23,0,0,1,36,36.81a17.36,17.36,0,0,1-6,5.13,17.36,17.36,0,0,1-6-5.13,16.23,16.23,0,0,1-3.16-9.63V20.25L30,17.66l9.14,2.59Z" />
</vector>
```

Вот так показывает Android Studio мне иконку:

[image: Отображение в Android studio]

Comment: какие иконки и откуда импортировали? из `android.R`?

Comment: нет, свои svg формат, были импортированы в проект

Comment: через добавление в `res/drawable`? а в чем некорректность отображения?

Comment: да, иконки добавлны в `res/drawable`. И ак вы можете увидеть из исправления вопросв. проблема в том что нарушается линии и/или кривые

Comment: картинки посмотреть не могу. Но вероятно, дело в разных dpi тестовых экранов. Могу посоветовать: либо добавлять png вместо svg, либо рисовать иконки программно с учетом dpi, либо под каждый dpi спецификатор добавить свой xml. Возможно, есть способ проще, которого я не знаю :)

Comment: @Jarvis_J есть разные способы, но то, что посоветовали вы (не про замену вектора растром), абсолютно не приемлемо для xml-графики. она специально задумывалась, чтобы уйти от разделения на dpi (масштабируемость под любую плотность основное преимущество)

Comment: @pavlofff, видите, как здорово, что вы всегда можете поправить мои комментарии к вопросу :)

Comment: У вас кривая SVG в Path делаются 2 лишние точки, такие линии нельзя делать в 1 PATH. В вашем случае так работает fill в SVG замените его на линии увидите все проблемы заодно и исправите всё. Я пропускаю через студию и вижу аналогичные ошибки, что вы показываете. У вас такое скорей всего возникает когда SVG суппорт либой преобразоывается в растр. Просто пропустите вашу же VD -> SVG -> VD и получаются картинки которые вы показываете

Comment: У меня подобная проблема была. Проверьте свое изображение в редакторе (illustrator например), все ли линии замкнуты + проверьте последовательность слоёв, скорее всего у вас где-то незамкнутая линия просто. На крайняк можете скинуть файл и я посмотрю у себя.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Подскажите пожалуйста, что вы имеете в виду под "Просто пропустите вашу же VD -> SVG -> VD" и под fill вы имеете в виду атрибут fillColor?

Comment: @DanteQuo Спасибо за идею, я просмотрел мои корявые иконки в illustrator всё в порядке, линии замкнуты